# With EKS using Fargate - how is it setup to know how to scale? What is the default profile of a node in Fargate?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate, eksctl

When EKS is setup with Fargate using `eksctl`  --fargate, what is being done there?

How many nodes are being run?
What are the values of the node?  (memory? cpu?)
How does EKS know how to scale when a pod is created? (how does it know how many nodes to run, and the configuration of the nodes?

How can I see the default profile from the command line or web app UI?

These seem like questions anyone would want to ask up front, but on the EKS page/documentation or Fargate, there is no link to information

Answer (score 0):

This page has some of the information you have questions about: https://eksctl.io/usage/fargate-support/

There is always a 1:1 mapping between pods and "nodes" so the number of "nodes" is always the same as the number of pods in an EKS/Fargate only cluster:

```
Fargate runs each pod in a VM-isolated environment without sharing resources with other pods.
```

(From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html)

> How can I see the default profile from the command line or web app UI?

Open the EKS console, open your cluster, go to `Configuration` and then `Compute`. There you will see your Fargate profiles. Or alternatively use [this CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/list-fargate-profiles.html).

We document how pods are sized [here in the EKS/Fargate docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html).